# How to define "evolution"?

Tags: evolution

The standard answer found in intro course to evolutionary biology to the question:

> what is evolution?

is:

> It is a change in allele frequency over time!

I believe a complete definition should encompass the following concepts:

- mutations
- copy number variation ([CNV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-number_variation))
- codon usage
- chromosome numbers
- phenotypic change (whether heritable or not)
- Complex phenotypic trait such as plasticity and developmental noise
- maybe some other things...

My questions are:

1. Would it be worth it to talk about phenotype in a definition of evolution?
2. What are the alternative definitions that have been proposed?
3. What is your definition?

---

Note: I would rather talk about genetic evolution, but if you think it is worth making one definition for genetic and cultural (and some other stuff maybe) evolution, you're free to suggest it!

Comment: Asking the what our individual definitions are is too subjective. Also, are you looking for a definition? Or an explanation. You mention "worth"... worth to who?

Comment: @Sancho I think a definition is never objective. It is totally arbitrary to decide what is hidden behind the word "evolution". Therefore, I would have expected several suggestions of definition. I guess a good definition is a definition that fits quite well the everybody sense of what is the boarder of a concept. "Worth" to any individual person willing to answer this question.

Comment: @Sancho Explanation? Explanation of what? I don't think I'm expecting any explanation about the science of evolutionary biology. I guess my question is close to a question of philosophy but I expected better answer by posting here than on philosophy beta.

Comment: @Remi.b Are there "wrong" answers to this question, then?

Comment: @Remi.b What is wrong with "It is a change in allele frequency over time". What things does that not include as evolution that it should? What things does it include as evolution that it shouldn't?

Comment: @Sancho "It is a change in allele frequency over time" does not encompass some concepts that I listed in my question. No, there might have no True answers but rather useful answers. That makes my question rather a philosophical question but I guess evolutionary biologists are better than philosopher to define "evolution".

Comment: @Remi.b The quality of a definition is not whether or not it "encompasses concepts". That's why I thought you were looking for an explanation. The quality of a definition is how well it *demarcates*. What is an example of an occurence that *is* evolution, but the definition "change in allele frequency over time" says *is not* evolution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11432/discussion-between-sancho-and-remi-b)

Comment: I think you are confusing a definition of evolution with a complete description of evolution. the first should be a sentence the second should be  several books worth of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is evolution?**

In a non-biological sense, *evolution* means change:

> ["a process of [...] change"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/evolution)

Biological evolution (seeing as this is *Biology* stack exchange) then needs to be tweaked to give a biologically specific context. Many textbooks etc. give definitions of evolution and here are a few good ones from across the history of evolutionary biology:

*Charles Darwin:*

> ["Descent with modification"](http://www.fossilmuseum.net/Evolution/DarwinsFinches.htm).

*Mark Ridley<sup>1</sup>:*

> ["Evolution means change, change in the form and behaviour of organisms between generations. ... When members of a population breed and produce the next generation we can imagine a lineage of populations, made up of a series of populations through time. Each population is ancestral to the descendant population in the next generation: a lineage is an ancestor-descendent series of populations. Evolution is then change between generations within a population lineage."](https://www.blackwellpublishing.com/ridley/)

*Brian and Deborah Charlesworth<sup>2</sup>:*

> ["Evolution means cumulative change over time in the characteristics of a population of living organisms. ... All evolutionary changes require initially rare genetic variants to spread among the members of a population, rising to high frequency..."](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0981519423)

**All of these have a common theme. Biological information is moving through time, descending with a degree of directionality (e.g. parent $\rightarrow$ offspring), and the information is modified with time.**

*Personally I would define evolution as:*

> Evolution is a change in gene frequencies, resulting from four mechanisms (mutation, migration, drift, and selection) which can all affect the transmission of heritable genetic information within populations. Evolution has the potential to cause phenotypic change (when genotype affects phenotype) and has the potential to cause both adaptation (microevolution) and divergence (macroevolution).

This definition captures that biological evolution occurs through changes in heritable genetic information, the prerequisites of evolution, the mechanisms of evolution, and what the consequences of those changes can be.

I think it is important to include mutation (and drift, selection, and migration) because these explicitly state how evolution occurs. I don't think it is necessary to include copy number variation, chromosome numbers, or codon usage as they are not central to the process of evolution (though they *can* be important).

Whilst only the first sentence of my definition is critical, I think it useful to include the latter part (or something of a similar effect) whenever possible as it helps to clarify evolution and it's relevance.

---

1. *ISBN: 978-1-4051-0345-9*
2. *ISBN: 978-0-9815-1942-5*

Comment: Nice +1. It is good to have this short review of definitions. I like your definition, I would just note that often when talking about divergence, people are talking about neutral molecular divergence and not phenotypic divergence. Thanks

Comment: The problem with defining it as only change from these four sources is when we find other sources of change, like recombination, engineering, or possibly extinction. The entire second sentence of your definition does not belong in a definition, it is accessory information. It is like a inserting a specific reference to kin selection in the definition it does not need ot be there. Worse it tires to define other terms as well, many will disagree that divergence=macroevolution.

Comment: @John recombination doesn't change gene frequencies, extinction will either occur through selection or drift, and one could argue that mutation also includes engineering (if you mean changing the genes). The second sentence is there to clarify that phenotypic change and evolution are not synonymous terns.

Comment: Also why do you not think that divergence is macroevolution?

Comment: Depends on the organisms, in unicellular organisms it can lead to speciation by creating a novel combination of existing genes. divergence does not have to result in speciation speciation while macro evolution is defined by occurring at or above the species level. More importantly not all macroevolution is a result of divergence. Wiping out part of a ring species for instance would create speciation while not creating any new genes or structures. They are closely related but not identical. but more importantly you should not be defining one term in the definition of another.

Comment: I'd argue that wiping out the middle of a ring species is not divergence or speciation either, the species remaining at the ends are already diverged from one another prior to removing the connection @John

Comment: they had already diverged but they were not separate species until the middle were wiped out,  It is most definitely a speciation event directly caused by the death, without it it is not speciation. But this debate itself shows another problem with the definition by adding unnecessary terms it makes the definition evern more open to interpretation and confusion. The accessory information should not be part of a definition,  A definition is for defining something not listing all the possible outcomes of it.

Comment: I really don't understand why you have such a big issue with the answer. I even addressed that the second part is not necessary in the original answer (see the last paragraph). The fact is that the answer defines evolution as it is understood within the field, genetic change by any of the four mechanisms - there are no other mechanisms. Removing the middle of a ring species may be a speciation event, but it's not evolution. @john

Comment: debatable, it is essentially an extreme form of genetic drift, but the argument itself is why all the extra stuff should not be part of a definition. The first seven words of your defintion all all that are needed for a definition, the rest of it really adds nothing to it as a  definition. There is no benefit in defining it as only those four mechanisms becasue there could be others, but those new mechanisms would still be evolution.

Comment: Well that's is your opinion. Personally I think the extra detail in the answer add to the definition to help make cleat what evolution is not. Perhaps we can just accept that we have different opinions on that. Something that you should note, however, is that it is well accepted in the research community that these are the four possible mechanisms of evolution, there's not much else that could occur - they kind of cover all the bases @John

Answer (score 2):

Theoretical biology spans multiple disciplines and the unaccompanied term *evolution* is defined differently in each:

As such chemical evolution is different from time evolution in physics and many other systems in theoretical biology that "evolve". These do play a role in theoretical biology.

Also, what `standard answer` to `evolution` in the field of theoretical biology are you referring to?

I recall learning that an allele as a special[:species:] gene variant, is defined as such as being present in at least one percent of the population. That definition has broadened [meanwhile](http://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/glossary=allele). A definition that has broadened.

Point in case, I don't believe there to be an evolutionary master-framework to (yet) exist, along the lines of desires for a *Theory of Everything* in physics.

On the other hand, as soon as you cross the boundaries of biological evolution, like let's say in the most primitive of living, biological entities, you are bound to cross over to *cultural evolution* as well. ( I am no expert on the subject, there are probably other intermittent steps as well). Synergistic effects in the process of evolution may even be considered in *Quorum Sensing's* most favorite model: *Vibrio fischeri*.

A simple search on the subject instantly yielded me:

> "Evolution of alkaline phosphatase in marine species of Vibrio". J Bacteriol....

In other words: molecular evolution, as being part of the many evolutiony research focuses.

The idea and gross effects of Darwinian evolution are often rather straightforward at first glance. All the little details, that have to be accounted for -with scientific rigor-, as science itself is evolving, are probably where the team-work starts, as do the discussion.

So the only fixture you can count on is *team* in *science*.

The introduction to the evolutionary topic at hand, that you would use in an abstract or introduction would depend on the scientific sub-discipline, and would likely already be readily available through peer-publication.